# The value disappears in an array where elements are object

Tags: angularjs

Here's the code:

```
$scope.get_candidate();
console.log($scope.voteData);

$scope.get_candidate = function () {
            var postData = {
                department: $scope.voteData.department,
                group: $scope.voteData.group
            };
            $http.post('/admin/r_candidate', postData)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.voteData.candidates = response.data.candidateInfos;
                });
        };
```

The console prints:

```
Object {candidates: Array[0], vote_begin: true, department: "机械与运载工程学部", vote_type: "预选", ballot_type: "记分"}
```

We can see candidates is an empty array and when I make a http post request with $scope.voteData, the candidates is empty. but when I see the detail:

```
Object
ballot_type:"记分"
candidates:Array[4]
department:"机械与运载工程学部"
vote_begin:true
vote_type:"预选"
__proto__:Object
```

We can see candidates has four elements which is what I expect because $http.post('/admin/r_candidate', postData) returns :

```
 {status: 0, data: {candidateInfos: [,…], total: 4}}
data:{candidateInfos: [,…], total: 4}
```

I do not know why candidates becomes an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

It's a recurring logic issue with async javascript.

When you run

```
$scope.get_candidate(); //async data inside
console.log($scope.voteData);
```

It will run the `console.log()` faster than you get result from the $http `request`

You can / should handle results inside the `success` function

```
$http.post('/admin/r_candidate', postData)
  .success(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.voteData.candidates = response.data.candidateInfos;
});
```

This said, depending on your angularjs version, you should use [the .then syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: I think that "faster" is an inappropriate choice of word: even if the query is fast enough to come back before any `console.log` following it, this won't matter.

Comment: thanks. "Promise" is the best solution to my question